# Offsetting calculations to the GPU

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, gpu

I'm performing a large number of calculations. Each calculation is independent of every other, in other words, the task could be parallelized and I'd like to offset the job to the GPU.

Specifically, I'm creating light/shadow maps for an OpenGL application, and the calculations are a bunch of Vector math, dot products, square roots, etc.

What are my options here? Does OpenGL natively support anything like this, or should I be looking for an external library/module?

Comment: I don't know about OpenGL, but I know CUDA supports it. Are you targeting any specific platform? If so, and it's CUDA enabled, you may want to check it out. There's a few .NET solutions out there - https://cudafy.codeplex.com would be a good place to start looking. It even supports translation to OpenCL, although I've never tried it.

Comment: I'm writing for Windows and MacOS and was under the impression CUDA only worked with Nvidia cards. I'll check it out.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by platform I meant the video card. It does indeed only work for Nvidia cards, which is why I mentioned it. It does supposedly translate to OpenCL, which works on all platforms, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute shader is the generic for CUDA, which is like an enhanced compute for nVidia. Note you don't need to use either, you can do calaculations using a vertex -> geomerty stream, or render to a pixel shader. So long as you can represent the results as a collection of values (a vertex buffer or texture), you can use the rendering pipeline to do your maths.

Comment: I've been pursuing that idea all evening, you're right, I think it's way to go.